Which word gets emphasized in a cumulative adjective?
I was wondering if anyone can clarify which word or adjective gets emphasized in a cumulative adjective — is it the first word or the last word (the one closest to the noun)?
I have included two sources which seem to be saying different things (unless I'm misinterpreting them):
"English Grammar for Dummies" — "sometimes one descriptive word is clearly more important than the rest...e.g. 'a funny, little, cocktail hat'. Here you're giving equal weight to each of the three descriptions. Do you really want to do so? Probably not,you're likely to be emphasising that it's a cocktail hat....and would write it as a 'funny little cocktail hat' "(last word before noun)
However on www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives.htm  — "The order can change for emphasis too. If there were two old waiters, one Italian and one Spanish, then..... the word "Italian" would be emphasized in "the Italian old waiter" (first word, furthest from noun)
any help is appreciated, thanks

Please quote more of your sources; it's absolutely impossible to tell what English Grammar for Dummies is talking about.

@StuartF added more source from dummies book

I agree with OP that the information in the two websites are contradictory.  Here English Grammar for Dummies is incorrect. Please note:
Adjectives closer to the noun carry less emphasis, being more inherent or specific.
I. The order of Adjectives - Ex. 1:.
OP has given 2 examples. The first example is:

you're likely to be emphasising that it's a cocktail hat....and would write it as a 'funny little cocktail hat' "(last word before noun)

In this "cocktail" functions as a noun adjunct forming a compound noun in "cocktail hat".  In compound nouns the first noun specifies a type for the second noun eg. "Wedding dress", "Birthday cake"
Typically, noun adjuncts precede the modified noun.
II. The order of Adjectives - Ex. 2:.
The website has given a complete list to show how adjectives should be placed. As per the rule "Italian old waiter" is incorrect and "old Italian waiter" is better.
They then attempted to clarify that there is some flexibility and that these rules are not set in stone.
They used the example of a hotel with both Spanish and Italian waiters to illustrate their point. Therefore, we can use "Italian old waiter" to instantly identify the Italian waiter. (Just to explain the concept, the adjective "old" is added.") This is provided by the website to provide a more thorough explanation of the concept. It should not be interpreted as permission to disregard the rule. (See attached photos below)

The Order of Adjectives
When two or more adjectives are strung together, they should be ordered according to the following list:


Please note that they said that "Italian old waiter" is incorrect but then they showed a special case where it can be considered correct




That chart is really confusing because there's too much information and size of the type is very hard on the eyes. Using screenshots like that ain't great.

Edit
In

funny little cocktail hat

cocktail hat is a type of hat.
The emphasis hence is the nearest adjective little.
In the second example comparing the Italian old waiter with another old waiter, the nationality is the emphasis.
Here old is almost already treated as part of the phrase old waiter.
The usual way we refer to this waiter would be the old Italian waiter, with the focus Italian.

And cocktail hat is a phrase defining a type of hat; cocktail isn't an adjective like funny and little.

Thanks again, @Kate Bunting.   I've added that point to the answer.

@KateBunting In the UK, ladies put on a special hat when they're having cocktails? Is it like the American beer hat, with tubes you can drink from, but it's a martini instead of beer?  https://www.amazon.com/Yellow-Helmet-Drinking-24-store/dp/B00Z0L6HMY

@TimR - :-) I don't know, I never drink cocktails! But see this.

How can the focus be Italian in the old Italian waiter?

@SeowjoohengSingapore So you're saying that the closest adjective to the noun is the one that is given greater emphasis, it's just that you don't recognise cocktail in cocktail hat and old in old waiter are adjectives, correct?
